# Laravel 5.8 - FileSystem Storage::url() Extremely Slow

Tags: php, laravel

I have my application configured to use Rackspace. The issue is when it comes to converting the direct path of the file in the container to the actual URL.

Example:

This:

> `assets/lBgPJsYEFOrROMAN0brwxSERRC6WgBo5lZHhYKEO.jpeg`

To:

> `http://e6450b1f45645dgd-d856017a5456546453bb76fb097937431.r69.cf3.rackcdn.com/assets/lBgPJsYEFOrROMAN0brwxSERRC6WgBo5lZHhYKEO.jpeg`

I store the direct path of the file in the container in each row in the database table and use

```
Storage::url($this->foo);
```

in my resource to get the URL in order for it to be returned in the response and displayed to the user.

Controller:

```
$assets = Asset::where->orderBy($order_by, $sort_by)->paginate($per_page);

return AssetResource::collection($assets);
```

AssetResource:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Asset extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'file' => Storage::url($this->file);
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

> Removing the line 'file' => Storage::url($this->file); drastically
>   improves performance.
>
> Response Time **With** Storage::url(): 6110ms / 5680ms / 4550ms /
>   6310ms
>
> Response Time **Without** Storage::url(): 173ms / 260ms / 117ms /
>   118ms

How could this be solved or improved upon?

Comment: I am assuming Rackspace is some kind of cloud storage and the call Storage::url() connects to the remote server. I do not use Rackspace myself, but Laravel documentation states the following: An absolute must for performance is to use a cached adapter. You will need an additional package for this: league/flysystem-cached-adapter ~1.0 - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

php artisan storage:link